Difference between jets and inclusive hadron production
I know both jets and inclusive hadron production are measured in high energy collisions. Is the difference just the way you measure it, or are there differences in the process behind them? If you measure a single hadron in a jet is it an inclusive reaction?
Also, when would you want to study one over the other?
